# UITableViewCell with a common element

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a scenario where in I need to create around 10 different prototypes of UITableViewCells. How ever all of these cells have some UI Elements (area marked in black) in common. And there is an area (marked in yellow) which is different for all these prototypes.

Is there a way I can abstract all the common UI Elements like the way it is done for contentView in UITableViewCell?

I tried to create a TableViewCell with all these elements and empty UIView to hold the customizations and planned to programatically load UIView (created in separate xib) into it.

The problem is I am not able to load the UIView into the UITableViewCell without loosing the constraints?

How to load a custom view with constraints into another?

Or Is there a way to create a custom UITableViewCell like the one in IB?

Comment: http://imgur.com/ebHuusC - image for my tableviewcell layout

Answer (score 0):

1. Create LoadableFromXibView subclass
2. Create a xib file, set the File's owner as your subclass
3. Drag outlets and design your view as usual
4. In your cell insert a subview that will be your reusable part of the cell and set its name as the new LoadableFromXibView subclass that you have created.

Source here: https://gist.github.com/DenHeadless/c3d682e7f499113109d6

```
    class LoadableFromXibView: UIView { 

    var view = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromXib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        backgroundColor = .clearColor()
        addSubview(view)
    }

    private func loadViewFromXib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(self.dynamicType), bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        return view
    }
    }
```